# Controlling the distribution of a points along a straight line

Tags: functions

I'm really struggling with what I think is a basic problem.

I'm a designer trying to code an add-on for Blender. That's not important to the problem, just thought I'd provide some context. And try to make the excuse for why I'm pretty poor at maths.

Anyway, the problem:

I have a line illustrated in figure 1 the image below:
[image]
Its length (A) can be specified by the user.

There are an amount of points along the line (B) which can also be specified by the user.

I need to be able to specify C to be between a value of 0 and 1, where 1 spaces the points out evenly (figure 1) but a value of 0 spaces the points out more akin to figure 2. And values in between start bunching the distribution of points towards the end of the line. Whatever this value is set to it can not affect the length of the line (A). That always has to remain as set.

Is there a formula to describe the behaviour?

It's easy to implement the behaviour in figure 1 and I have managed to get the distribution of the points to bunch up towards the end as the value (C) is changed. However, the length of the line (A) scales too.

Hope I've explained this appropriately.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are an unlimited number of functions to accomplish this kind of transformation. A simple one can be defined as follows. Given $L$ the segment length, the function with $0 < c \le 1$ and $0 \le x\le L$

$$
f(x) = \left(\frac xL\right)^{\frac 1c}L
$$

gives a correspondence $\{x\to f(x)\}$ as desired

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer. I'm going look into this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

In short you're looking for a function $f : [0, L] \to [0, L]$ such that

1. $f$ is strictly increasing,
2. $f(0) = 0$,
3. $f(A) = A$, and
4. $f\left(\frac{A}{B - 1}\right) = C$.

Note that this formulation requires $0 < C < A$ and $B > 2$.)

You don't say what exactly you mean by "akin to figure 2", but I'll suppose you mean that:

5. The sequence of distances between successive pairs of points, that is, $$\delta_i := f\left(\frac{i}{B - 1}\right) - f\left(\frac{i - 1}{B - 1}\right), \qquad i = 0, \ldots, B - 1,$$ is (not necessarily strictly) increasing or decreasing.

A simple family of functions that satisfies these conditions (1), (2), (3), and (5) is
$$\boxed{g(x) := A^{1 - \alpha} x^\alpha , \qquad \alpha > 0} .$$
Substituting this function in equation (4) gives
$$g\left(\frac{A}{B - 1}\right) = C ,$$ that is,
$$\alpha = \log \left[ \frac{A}{(B - 1) C}\right].$$ (Notice that the quantity inside the logarithm is just the ratio $\frac{A}{B - 1}$ of the distance between evenly spaced points and the target length $C$.) For $c = \frac{1}{\alpha}$ this example coincides with Cesareo's suggestion for some values of $\alpha$.

Other families of functions satisfying (1), (2), (3), and (5) include
$$\boxed{h(x) := A \sin^{\beta} \left(\frac{\pi x}{2 A}\right) , \qquad 0 < \beta < 1} ,$$
and
$$\boxed{j(x) := A^{1 - 2 \gamma} \left(2 A x - x^2\right)^\gamma, \qquad \gamma > 0}.$$
We can find a value of $\beta$ satisfying condition (4) iff $\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2 (B - 1)}\right) \leq \frac{C}{A}$, and we can always find a value of $\gamma$ so that $j$ satisfies (4).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer. And thanks for correct my typing mistake! I'm going look into this and get back to you. Additionally, that you for going into a great amount of detail in your response.

Comment: Although I've accepted the answer above based on it providing the level of simplicity I require for my simple use-case, I will eventually require more control so I will come back to your answer for a greater understanding. Really appreciate your explanation. Thanks.